# python program not running

Tags: python

I was making somes script in Python via PyCharm CE 2018.3.4,but when I run this script it will never show me results,and it will never end. Is it because of PyCharm or because script.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def trade_spider(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <=1:
        url = "https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=car&_sacat=0&_pgn="+str(page)
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text,"html.parser")
        for link in soup.findAll('a',{'class' :'item-name' }):
            href = link.get('href')
            title = link.string
            print(href)
            print(title)

trade_spider(2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have an infinite loop:

```
page = 1
while page <= 1:
    # Code in which page never changes
```

`page` is *always* `1`, so you have no way of leaving the loop.

As for not printing anything, you continually fetch the first page from that site.  A simple `print` of the result shows that there are no `class` entries on that page.  Thus, there is nothing to print.

Try this instead:

```
for page in range(1, max_pages+1):
    url = "https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=car&_sacat=0&_pgn="+str(page)
```

Answer (score 0):

Main statement for your while loop is: `while page <=1:` but it just never increase, 'page' value is always 1. If you want it to crawl 2 pages, like you're trying to do i believe it should be something like this:

```
def trade_spider(max_pages):
    page = 1
    #Loop until page number equals max_pages value
    while page <= max_pages:
         url = "https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=car&_sacat=0&_pgn="+str(page)
         source_code = requests.get(url)
         plain_text = source_code.text
         soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text,"html.parser")
         for link in soup.findAll('a',{'class' :'item-name' }):
             href = link.get('href')
             title = link.string
             print(href)
             print(title)
         #Increment page so it crawls next one on each iteration
         page+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a code problem. You are setting page = 1 and never incrementing the value. So the while loop is never ending.